# Let $V$ be an inner product space and $a,b,c \in V$ distinct points. If $\|c-a\| = \|c-b\| + \|b-a\|$ then $c-a = \lambda (b-a)$, $\lambda \geq 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

**My attempt**

I called $x = c-b $ and $y = b-a$.

Then $\|x+y\| = \|c-a\| = \|c-b\| + \|b-a\| = \|x\|+\|y\|$.

The equality holds in the triangle inequality, thus $x= t\cdot y$ or $y= t\cdot x$, $t \geq 0$.

If $t=0$ then $b=c$ or $b=a$, but the points are distinct, thus we have $t > 0$.

We have two cases:

**a)** $x= t\cdot y \Rightarrow c-b = t(b-a) \Rightarrow c-a = t(b-a) + b-a = (t+1)(b-a)$

Take $\lambda = t+1 > 1$  and we have $c-a = \lambda (b-a)$

**b)** $y= t\cdot x \Rightarrow b-a = t(c-b) \Rightarrow c-b = \frac{1}{t}(b-a) \Rightarrow  c-a = \frac{1}{t}(b-a) + b-a = (\frac{1}{t}+1)(b-a)$

Take $\lambda = t+1 > 1$  and we have $c-a = \lambda (b-a)$.

Am I right? I'm not sure because my $\lambda$'s are strictly greater than 1.

Comment: You are right, $\lambda > 1 \implies \lambda \ge 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine. Concerning your doubt about $\lambda>1$ versus $\lambda\geq 1$, notice that if $\lambda = 1$, then

$$c-a = \lambda(b-a) = b-a,$$

and so $c=b$, contradicting that the points are distinct. This means that $\lambda=1$ is not possible, and $\lambda>1$ is the best that you can get.